# Package availible but not in dpkg.log

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I need to know when a package was installed.

I search /var/log/dpkg.log* for that and search for the installation-entry.

Sometimes I have a package installed that is not part of the log. I never removed any log.

How it that possible and whats the meaning of that?

I use

> apt list --installed

for listing all available packages.

I am running Debian 11.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I’m aware, the core packages installed during installation don’t appear in `dpkg.log`.

On top of that, if you have `logrotate` installed, `dpkg.log` will be rotated every month, with twelve copies kept. This means that packages installed more than twelve months ago (rounded down) won’t appear in `dpkg.log*`. The fact that you have `dpkg.log*` files other than `dpkg.log` suggests that you have `logrotate` installed.

You can determine when a package was last touched by `dpkg` (installed or upgraded) by checking the timestamp of the corresponding `.list` file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` (although [upgrades will only touch this if the list of installed files changes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627860/86440)).